# check if a number ends up with either XX,5 or is an integer in python

Tags: python

I can solve it using multiple ifs and right function... but was wondering if there were a nicer solution...

as an example

```
10,5 would return true
10 would return true
9,3 would return false
9,5 would return true
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show what you have at the moment anyway, it could be useful.

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by `XX,5`. Should that be a two-digit number to the left of the '`,`', or any number? You say `9,5` should be true. Are these inputs strings or floats?

Answer (score 2):

Use regex:

```
import re
def int_or_comma_5(n):
    return re.match('\d+(,5)?$',n)
```

Comment: By far the superior solution!

Comment: Every time I suggest regex to someone, in my head I have the voice from that FedEx Super Bowl commercial from several years ago with the "employee" who was just a cardboard cutout and a recording saying "Why don't we use FedEx?" Except in my case it's "why don't you use RegEx?"